# Anaconda runs when I right-click the arrow button instead of showing the menu

Tags: anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda Navigator, and it opens fine. However, I have a problem: when I try to right-click the arrow button to open the menu for a prompt, it runs the environment as if I were left-clicking.

[image: Anaconda GUI]

I want to open a prompt of my environment from the menu that should open when right-clicking.